# How to extend a component in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, migration, vuejs3, element-plus

The import is working just fine in case I try to use the component from `element-plus` directly.

What I'm trying to do though, is to extend a component from `element-plus` library (it uses the `composition api` from Vue 3) and add some additional properties to my component and methods.

In Vue 2 it would look something like this:

```
export default {
  extends: SomeComponent
}
```

In Vue 3 this seems to not be working anymore.

I've read about [defineComponent](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent) but so far, without success implementing it.

Can someone shed me some lights? Thanks.

Comment: I want to extend an ElementPlus component and then use my component which will have some additional stuff

Comment: Hi @pmpc did you find a way for this issue ? I am also having the same problem now. how can we extend 'El Tree' component in custom component ?

Comment: Yes @SandyKrish. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to extend a component that uses Composition API whereas another still uses Options API, we need to also do the setup, such as:

`export default { extends: SomeComponent, setup: SomeComponent.setup }`

Comment: This worked in Nuxt 3. Thanks